# How can I set the parent category when I save the category?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am developing a restful application using spring and hibernate.

I am posting this JSON

```
  {
     "name": "Test Category",
     "parent": 2
   }
```

From this, I am unable to get the parent ID in my controller post method. When I use theCategory.getParent(), It returns null.

Here is my controller post method.

```
@PostMapping("/categories")
public Category addCategory(@RequestBody Category theCategory) {


    System.out.println("The parent category : " + theCategory.getParent());

    // set id to 0
    theCategory.setId(0);
    categoryService.saveCategory(theCategory);

    return theCategory;

}
```

what is the best way to set parent category, when I save category ? Here is my category class - https://github.com/iyngaran/test/blob/master/Category.java

Comment: You need to get `theCategory` (the real one in DB) using a repository (or any other that queries the DB) and get the parent through that entity you got from DB.

Comment: Show us Category class, if I understand correctly the problem appears before you hit the dB, in the model binding phase.

Comment: Here is my category class - https://github.com/iyngaran/test/blob/master/Category.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `@JsonIgnore` on your `getParent()`. This is why you get null on your object.

(When you remove `@JsonIgnore` you will get a binding error).
Therefore, I suggest you post a DTO object, not entity. 
In this dto object you can map the parent to integer, while in the `Category` class you can have it mapped to `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

RequestBody must be a DTO, in the addCategory method you need to get the parent Category (entity) by searching it byId.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your class , your json should be like

```
{
   "name": "Test Category",
   "parent": {
          "id": 2,
    }
}
```